# How to visualise an XML file

Tags: xml

I found this freeware app, labytrinth, three years ago (though it had last been updated in 2005). It allowed writers to organise characters and other elements of their stories. One would create elements and then drag them onto a window where one could connect the different elements with arrows, adding information about the nature of the relationships.

My computer crashed recently and, while I did not lose any files because everything was neatly backed up, I did not have a copy of the app itself. The website I had taken it from (habitualindolence.net) is gone (as the helpful user of Writers found out for me) and, though I am still trying to reach anyone who may still possess it, my hopes are not high.

Nevertheless, I have the files (plt extension); now I just need to visualise them. Following the advice of Writers' users, I opened the file with Notepad, which gave me a readable code. Someone suggested it could be Python but an online Python visualiser gave syntax errors. Another user mentioned it is an XML file.

Can anyone recommend a way to visualise the code? Here's the first few lines. If you require a longer excerpt, please let me know.

Introductory segment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<Project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SaveFormat>3.5</SaveFormat>
  <Name>TheNewWorld_01_AmbitiousPrince</Name>
```

Segment for the part where the characters are listed:

```
      <Elements>
        <Element>
          <ID>f9434e21-d471-466f-948b-107f9da58905</ID>
          <Name>*Nyan Cleaner</Name>
          <Type>Character</Type>
          <Annotations>
            <TextAnnotation>
              <ID>dad71ecc-d38a-45e2-a695-d6ad0d679f57</ID>
              <Title>Physical Description</Title>
              <Content>Long, brown hair
    brown eyes
    lightly tanned skin
    </Content>
              <RTF>{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2070{\fonttbl{\f0    \fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}}
    \viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs17 Long, brown hair\par
    brown eyes\par
    lightly tanned skin\par
    \par
    }
    </RTF>
```

Segment with the 'structures' tag that will list all the diagrams, each diagram ('structure' tag) being nested whithin the 'structures' tag.

```
  <Structures>
    <Structure>
      <ID>dc1f9607-32d7-42ac-abcd-8b27e066eca2</ID>
      <Name>Nyan_Connections</Name>
```

The 'structure' block is then composed of 'nodes' with positions (referring to the boxes with the name of the characters). (Note that the following segment shows up immediately after the previous segment)

```
    <Nodes>
        <Node>
          <ElementID>43a45855-529d-48d6-ad33-3602abd5e57c</ElementID>
          <Position>
            <X>0.8034632</X>
            <Y>0.221544713</Y>
          </Position>
        </Node>
        <Node>
          <ElementID>aa94de7a-2241-4e41-a383-eadb070354d0</ElementID>
          <Position>
            <X>0.219047621</X>
            <Y>0.8678862</Y>
          </Position>
```

Still within the 'structure' tag, you have the tag 'links' immediatelly after 'nodes' is closed. These refer to the arrows that connect the different nodes above.

```
  <Links>
        <Link>
          <ID>4eb83f93-2d47-4afc-bc46-dfa83a4f1f96</ID>
          <Description>Lovers</Description>
          <LHS>f9434e21-d471-466f-948b-107f9da58905</LHS>
          <RHS>c2b3f24d-c9f2-4832-b488-e1f3eca84b04</RHS>
          <Direction>Double</Direction>
        </Link>
        <Link>
          <ID>272dac28-a5f9-400c-a514-3aa9b971240f</ID>
          <Description>Friend</Description>
          <LHS>19f460ea-5ff9-4690-9adf-4b556489083e</LHS>
          <RHS>f9434e21-d471-466f-948b-107f9da58905</RHS>
          <Direction>Double</Direction>
        </Link>
```

Once the 'structures' tag is closed, we have the section for timelines (where the plots are plotted, in a table, with characters on the vertical; the timepoints, or chapters, in the horizontal; and the text of the plot elsewhere).

```
<Timelines>
    <Timeline>
      <ID>531b95f1-a07d-4aa8-ad2e-86576322f41b</ID>
      <Name>1-Ambitious_Ch02</Name>
```

This part is not as intuitive to read (at least for me). It includes the tags for the characters (ElementIDs), the chapters (Points), and then the plotted events, identifying what each character is up to in each chapter (TimelinePoint).

```
      <ElementIDs>
        <guid>f9434e21-d471-466f-948b-107f9da58905</guid>
        <guid>19f460ea-5ff9-4690-9adf-4b556489083e</guid>
        <guid>1ea36ec3-10e6-451d-a251-a139a51a6cfc</guid>
        <guid>c2b3f24d-c9f2-4832-b488-e1f3eca84b04</guid>
      </ElementIDs>
      <Points>
        <TimelinePoint>
          <ID>9699cb8e-367d-4119-936a-b43c3cf403e2</ID>
          <Name>scene1</Name>
          <UseSchedule>None</UseSchedule>
          <Schedule>0001-01-01T00:00:00</Schedule>
          <Items>
            <TimelineItem>
              <ID>63ca24bf-b278-4df3-a88f-4984cabc8404</ID>
              <ElementID>f9434e21-d471-466f-948b-107f9da58905</ElementID>
              <Annotation>
                <ID>c21bc9bb-7857-4099-97f4-14ef5b20b4f7</ID>
                <Title>Arrives to work</Title>
                <Content>She's late.</Content>
                <RTF>{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2070{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs17 She's late.\par
}
</RTF>
              </Annotation>
            </TimelineItem>
```

And yes, I suppose I could print all this, match the elementIDs to the characters in order to figure which character is connected to which and manually 'translate' it all but... hundreds of IDs? It must be faster finding a way to visualise it.

Not to mention that this coding seems really intuitive and HTML-like; I'm starting to wonder if I shouldn't just see the silver-lining of my near disaster and use it as a motivation to pick up XML?

EDIT (in response to Philip's comment)

I used the app to organise the characters and plot for a fantasy story spanning 5 books. I have the first 4 fully planned and the relationships of the characters annotated. I need to find a way to retrieve that information. Obviously, I can read through the code to get the text information (character list, etc), but the relationships between the characters are essential, that's why I need to visualise it. Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: What you are asking requires some level of coding skills. I am not sure what you are exactly looking for, do you have an image or something like that to show what you are after? If copy everthing within `<RTF>[…]</RTF>`, paste it in a text editor and save it as a rtf file, you can open it in word, or libre office…

Comment: I know I don't know anything about coding, but if I've learnt HTML and complex excel formulas all by myself (and surfing the net, obviously), I'm sure I'll be able to grasp the basics to make it readable. I mean, it's not like I have to actually create the code, it's all in the file... right?

Comment: There is no relationship in your code yet.

Comment: @jhinghaus I only posted the first few lines. The file itself is huge. It includes at least four separate diagrams, over fifty characters, and plots for the books. I can add more lines to the excerpt above. Should I add a list of all the tags used? Would that be helpful to find a way to visualise the diagram?

Comment: @SaraCosta Just add a bit more or some example segments with other tags.

Comment: Would it be helpful if I went through the whole file (a copy, that is), identified all the different elements and cut off extraneous ones (I mean, for testing and analysing, it's all the same having the +50 characters or just 4, right?). Then I can move on to the area of the 'structures' (I've gathered that the structure tag refers to the diagrams themselves) and cut off all the blocks that refer to the characters I cut off and maintain just the ones that refer to the characters I've retained.

Comment: Would that make it easier to analyse and test? I'll need to wait for the weekend though, because I'll have to go through each element very carefully to make sure I don't cut off anything essential. Of course that also requires that I can figure out the way the code gives the info to connect different elements...

Comment: Do you know: http://www.yworks.com/products/yed That editor is free and can build stuff like you need. It is possible to utilize XSLT to transform your document into the *.graphml format, which yed uses, since this is also XML based. But I guess you are faster if you just rebuild the data in that editor. If you have really big bunch of files, you would like to transform, this would be the I would take, but as already said, coding skills required and too much to explain here.

Comment: @philipp I also use YEd. So, do you mean that it is probably not possible to find a 'browser' to read this code? I better just sit down and crack it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after thinking again about the problem I have got another approach for you.
The XSLT thing could get hard with all those IDs to track.

I gave it a try using a python script and graphviz.
From your examples I made an anomized example file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<Project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SaveFormat>3.5</SaveFormat>
  <Name>TheNewWorld_01_AmbitiousPrince</Name>

  <Elements>
    <Element>
      <ID>f9434e21-d471-466f-948b-107f9da58905</ID>
      <Name>*Some One</Name>
      <Type>Character</Type>
    </Element>

    <Element>
      <ID>f9434e21-d471-466f-948b-107f9da58906</ID>
      <Name>*Some Other</Name>
      <Type>Character</Type>
    </Element>

    <Element>
      <ID>f9434e21-d471-466f-948b-107f9da58907</ID>
      <Name>A Third</Name>
      <Type>Character</Type>
    </Element>
  </Elements>

  <Structures>
    <Structure>
      <ID>dc1f9607-32d7-42ac-abcd-8b27e066eca2</ID>
      <Name>Some_Connections</Name>


    <Nodes>
        <Node>
          <ElementID>f9434e21-d471-466f-948b-107f9da58905</ElementID>
          <Position>
            <X>0.8034632</X>
            <Y>0.221544713</Y>
          </Position>
        </Node>
        <Node>
          <ElementID>f9434e21-d471-466f-948b-107f9da58906</ElementID>
          <Position>
            <X>0.219047621</X>
            <Y>0.8678862</Y>
          </Position>
        </Node>
        <Node>
          <ElementID>f9434e21-d471-466f-948b-107f9da58907</ElementID>
          <Position>
            <X>0.219047621</X>
            <Y>0.8678862</Y>
          </Position>
        </Node>
    </Nodes>
   <Links>
        <Link>
          <ID>4eb83f93-2d47-4afc-bc46-dfa83a4f1f96</ID>
          <Description>Lovers</Description>
          <LHS>f9434e21-d471-466f-948b-107f9da58905</LHS>
          <RHS>f9434e21-d471-466f-948b-107f9da58906</RHS>
          <Direction>Double</Direction>
        </Link>
        <Link>
          <ID>4eb83f93-2d47-4afc-bc46-dfa83a4f1f97</ID>
          <Description>Knows</Description>
          <LHS>f9434e21-d471-466f-948b-107f9da58905</LHS>
          <RHS>f9434e21-d471-466f-948b-107f9da58907</RHS>
          <Direction>Single</Direction>
        </Link>
   </Links>
    </Structure>
  </Structures>
</Project>
```

This file can be translated into SVG by these lines of python:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree
import graphviz

tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('example.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

# read all the structures
for structure in root.findall('.//Structures/Structure'):
    structure_name = structure.findtext('./Name')
    graph = graphviz.Digraph(format='svg',comment='structure_name')

    # read the nodes of the structure
    for node in structure.findall('.//Nodes/Node'):
        node_element_id = node.findtext('./ElementID')
        # find the name
        element_name = root.findtext(".//Elements/Element[ID='{}']/Name".format(node_element_id))
        graph.node(node_element_id, element_name)

    # read the links
    for link in structure.findall('.//Links/Link'):
        id_1 = link.findtext('./LHS')
        id_2 = link.findtext('./RHS')
        description = link.findtext('./Description')
        direction = link.findtext('./Direction')
        graph.edge(id_1, id_2, label=description)
        if direction=='Double':
            graph.edge(id_2, id_1, label=description)

    graph.render(filename=structure_name)
```

This creates a SVG with the name of the structure looking like this.

[image: Result]

It could look better by putting more effort into the graphviz part.

The timeline would be another thing.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion and the example. It has helped me decide which language to go for: Python. It'll take time, sure, but knowing the information is not lost is enough for now. That and starting studying coding. That's always fascinated me, I just had never had the right motivation to push me into.

Answer (score 1):

Apps like the one you used, have their own custom XML-Schemata. This means the app is the only thing understanding the meaning of the tags. Interpreting the XML to a diagram is a custom implementation in the app.

The app uses this `<SaveFormat>3.5</SaveFormat>` to know what to do with the data.

But as it is XML we could to use XSLT to transform the custom XML into a XML that is understood by another app. This is what XSLT is made for.

Sounds possible to me.

We need a target application and would take it step by step to make the elements show there ignoring the rest.

Comment: I've read a bit about XML and XSLT. It sounds interesting and familiar (I taught myself HTML back in 2005 and I also studied JavaScript, if only at an introduction level and a long time ago), so I'll have to sit down and see what will be more worthwhile: invest in studying XML and XSLT or trace the links manually from the IDs. If it were just a table, it would be easier (it seems to me) to make it work on a browser; but the arrow bit and 'floating' nodes make me feel the task wil be too time consuming. I'll have to consider both approaches carefully.